# 1 to 1 relationship does not work even when I define a shared primary key as well as foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, primary-key

I'm trying to set up a 1 to 1 relationship between two classes:

```
public class Player
{
    [Key]
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public string PlayerName { get; set; }
    public int PlayerRating { get; set; }
    public int PlayerSkill { get; set; }
    public virtual Record Record { get; set; }
}

public class Record
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Player")]
    public int RecordId { get; set; }
    public List<Player> RecordWins { get; set; }
    public List<Player> RecordLosses { get; set; }
    public virtual Player Player { get; set; }
}

public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Record> Records { get; set; }

    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
}
```

According to this [article](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx), I must define a primary key on Player.cs and a primary and foreign key on Record.cs (which I did).

When I migrate this change using:

```
Add-migration AddPlayerRecordRelationship
```

It didn't work. It says:

"*Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Player.Record' of type 'Record'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.*"

Is there anything I'm missing using this approach? I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: The problem is not with one-to-one relationship in question, but the two additional collection navigation properties `RecordWins` and `RecordLosses` which define two additional one-to-many relationships, which will need two additional FK properties/columns etc. And explicit fluent configuration of the 3 relationships.

Comment: You have to tell EF which of the thee possible properties in `Record` are the counterpart of `Player.Record`. It would be enough to add `[InverseProperty("Player")]` to the latter, but then EF will generate meaningless FK columns for the other two associations. As Ivan says, you better do it by fluent mapping.